# Conditional Sass Variables with Nativescript

Tags: sass, nativescript

Android and iOS render fonts in vastly different ways.  I'd like to be able to get their renders looking a little more similar, so I need to change the font-sizes and weights throughout my entire app depending on whether it's on iOS or android.

Obviously, going through every place font-size or weight is defined and adding a conditional for is out of the question, and (fortunately) I already have all my font sizes and weights defined by sass variables.

Regardless of whether or not there is a better solution than conditional sass variables, I would like to know:

How can I conditionally select sass variables in nativescript?

I know that modules will use `MyModule.ios.css` or `MyModule.android.css` depending on the os.  Can I take advantage of that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on right track. You can have MyVariable.android.scss and MyVariable.ios.scss to define different values for Sass variable. In my code sharing project I have `MyVariable.scss` as well that I use for HTML(Web).

I have created a sample playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0YAkBN).
In my home.component.ios.scss

```
$labelfontSize: 10;
$labelfontColor: red;
.home-panel{
    vertical-align: center; 
    font-size: 20;
    margin: 15;
}

.description-label{
    margin-bottom: 15;
    color: $labelfontColor;
    font-size: $labelfontSize;
}
```

and in my home.component.android.scss

```
$labelfontSize: 18;
$labelfontColor: green;
.home-panel{
    vertical-align: center; 
    font-size: 20;
    margin: 15;
}

.description-label{
    margin-bottom: 15;
    color: $labelfontColor;
    font-size: $labelfontSize;
}
```

It shows `red` text in ios while in `android` text is green.

Comment: How would I go about conditionally importing them.  I don't want to import both in every single file I use variables, and can not import from the root app.scss files.

Comment: You just need to import MyVariable.scss not the MyVariable.android.scss or ios one. based on platform it will be compiled.

Comment: Would you mind showing some code?  I don't think what you're saying will actually work for my case, but am having a hard time telling from just diction.

Comment: I have created a playground for you. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0YAkBN

Comment: Ah.  Thank you.  Just checked it out, and this does not do what I'm looking for.

I'd like to be able to change just the variables, without having to copy paste all of the css.